# My controller method it's loading data and exporting to another source , here I want to make this asynchronous

Tags: spring-boot, asynchronous

Here I want to make below code as asynchronous.
I read that `@Async` annotation if I add this annotation, does it enough or in main application also need to add here need to consider another point also, if I call this API multiple times second call should wait till completion of first call (example: I have called first time it may take 5 min to complete, but again i have called again in background the first call was still running, once the first call completed then only it has to start my second call).

```java
@Operation(summary = "load operation")
@PostMapping(value = "delta/load")
public void sendDeltaOutbound() {
    cppService.loadData();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncMethodApplication {

}
```

In method of service, you must have `@Async`

```java
@Service
public class FooService {

  @Async
  public BarFuture<Fuu> findFuuBaa(String baa) throws InterruptedException {
        // ...
  }

}
```

see https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/

Comment: does it covers request cal queue(like what i mention in the question), or we need to use @Scheduled annotation on top of this.